# MySQL.Data to Pomelo - MysqlReader changes

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I was looking to convert my script to Pomelo from Oracle, I am using EntityFramework for my script and using MySQL commands and readers to access my XenForo installation. When converting I have a line of code that `reader.GetInt32` which before was a string input but now it’s asking for a int. The column is the first column so would this be 1?

I.E

`reader.GetInt32(1)`?

Comment: No, the first column returned by the DataReader.Read is at index 0 (as for any other array in NET)

Comment: Okay thanks. So inputting 0 will read the row I require. Appreciated

Comment: Wait.... reader.GetInt32(0) returns the value (as integer) of the first _column_ of the current row. You loop over the rows returned by your query inside a _while(reader.Read())_ loop

Answer (score 0):

This missing API was added to MySqlConnector (the MySQL connector used by Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) [in v0.36.0](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/435). You should be able to use `reader.GetInt32("columnName")` if you update to the latest version of [MySqlConnector on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/).